# Why is file_get_contents can get remote data while PHP Curl gives blank page?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I am trying to download remote XML feed using PHP Curl , But PHP curl is giving me **blank page** while `php` function `file_get_contents` can get the contents.

i am trying to make php curl work as its faster than `file_get_contents` and can set multiple extra options.,

i am doing request curl like this.

```
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

and when i do `echo $data;` all i get is **blank page**.

but if i use `file_get_contents` instead , then i can get whole XML feed, why is that ?

i have tried setting

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

still it shows **blank page**.

i even tried

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

but when i use curl i get **blank page**.

i am using

```
Windows Version: Windows XP SP3 32-bit
XAMPP Version: 1.8.2
# php -v
PHP 5.4.31 (cli) (built: Jul 23 2014 20:20:15)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

How can i make the `PHP Curl` give me data instead of blank page. ?

Comment: What does the curl_error($ch) say?

Comment: @pamelus Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to domain.com 443